# Why/how is Visual Studio 2019 opening an old version of my code?

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2019

Suppose I have a solution containing a project containing `MyCode.cs`.  I put this solution in a local GIT repository and commit `MyCode.cs`, then I copy and paste another instance of this solution with a different version of `MyCode.cs` into the same containing folder via Windows Explorer.  Now if I open the file individually Visual Studio shows the contents of that actual file on the file system; however, if I open that file via the solution, I somehow get the content of the original file it overwrote!  Why is this happening?  How is this happening?  How do I make it stop happening?!  I think this is a bug in a recent update of Visual Studio 2019 since I've never seen this happen before.

Comment: Are you committing the code changes to git? Are you opening two different git repos? Does the solution cache documents that were open?

Comment: I've not committed the changes, the bottom bar of Visual Studio shows I'm still using the same repository so I suppose there is some sort of local caching going on - how would I find out?

Comment: Any chance you're viewing the committed version? Assuming no, the file after the copy should show up in your Git Changes window as edited. You should be able to right click it and view differences. If you open the solution version of the file (old copy), and edit it, what happens in the Git Changes window?

Comment: Are you overwting the files or copying them to a subdirectory? If you run `git status` and `git diff` are the files shown as changed (but not staged)? Have you restarted Visual Studio – maybe it is showing you a cached in-memory version of the files?

Comment: @knittl Even after a machine restart it's in the same state!  When I right-clicked in "Solution Explorer" and went to GIT, "Compare with Unmodified" was disabled.  I have just seen however, the change was listed as a pending change against the pencil mark in the bottom bar; the GIT Changes Window listed the file and let me select "Compare with Unmodified" was selectable - and there are my changes!  I've seen this issue without using the new GIT view elsewhere but am curious how it and explorer can see changes which Visual Studio cannot!

Comment: It's werid. Can you somehow "refresh" the solution in VS?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

I'm having a similar issue.  Scenario: I merge branch A into branch B and the merge goes through fine (nothing to stage).  There are "zero changes"...however, if I look at the file from solution explorer it shows an outdated file...if I step outside of Visual Studio and use TortoiseGit, it shows the correct file on the left and right of a compare...so there are clearly no changes...but VS is still showing the pre-merged copy.

Comment: @KevinNelson I'll need to confirm when it inevitably happens again, but I seem to recall doing a fetch in Visual Studio via the up arrow in the bottom bar updated the code I already had locally.  I've updated Visual Studio several times since this post and restarting it also seems to resolve the issue now.  Just for reference I'm currently running version 16.11.5.